# Specify a Proxy in config vs code for a WSE/SOAP web service

Tags: .net, proxy, wse3.0

Is there a way to specify a WSE3 proxy in the config file instead of code. 
I figured out how to get it working in code as follows:

```
valservice.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://10.192.xx.xx:8080", true);
```

Details: I have a WCF wrapper web service that is calling a WSE3 external vendor web service.  The WSE3 code was working fine when called from a form, but not when running under IIS as another web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you cannot use the normal appSettings for this?

See an [example here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151224171123/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mnf/articles/108602.aspx).

Comment: No, I was just guessing that there was a more standardized way to do it.  In WCF, there seem to be XML for everything, but maybe not with WSE3?

Comment: So the Proxy was indeed the connectivity issue as per your previous question then, I take it?

Comment: Wim - Yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752646/unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server/1757012#1757012  I put in my own answer there.